# Jquery Validation: Validate one field just once at submit

Tags: javascript

I need to validate a rule of one of my field only at every submit
I need all the other fields to keep being validated onfocusout.
When i click submit this specific rule should be validated once and then nothing until the next submit

Thanks!

Comment: add some code to our question as per requirement

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

You should add some code yo your question.

Anyway, my suggestion is to validate the form field in your submit function returning if the field doesn't meet your requirements.

In this case you will also have to take care of informing your user in case the field is invalid.